Как узнать id канала телеграмм зная его @username
используя aiogram 3.6 пайтон 3.12.1

По username никак. Можно переслать что-нибудь из канала боту, или добавить бота на канал, тогда в апдейте будет указан id

from aiogram import Bot

async def get_channel_id(username: str) -> int:
    bot = Bot(token="ТОКЕН")
    chat = await bot.get_chat(username)
    return chat.id

async def main():
    channel_username = "@username"
    channel_id = await get_channel_id(channel_username)
    print(f"ID канала {channel_username}: {channel_id}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())

